# Unknown provider: $cookies angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, angular-cookies

I have tried everything I can think of and I am still receiving this error.

app.js:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngCookies'
]).
config(['$cookies', function($cookies) {
  var cookie = $cookies.getObject();
  console.log(cookie);
}])
```

index.html:

```
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
```

bower.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.5.0",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.5.0"
  }
```

what could seriously be going wrong? I've tried looking at everything on stackoverflow/google regarding how to fix these bugs but I still receive

```
Unknown provider: $cookies
```

When I do not add $cookies into the .config() of my app.js file, I receive no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because you cannot inject a service into the configuration section as the services won't be initialized yet. So instead of `$cookies`, you should use `$cookiesProvider` inside `.config` block. And for some reason if you want to use $cookies inside your config, you can inject it manually. Give this a try

```
app.config(function() {
  var $cookies;
  angular.injector(['ngCookies']).invoke(['$cookies', function(_$cookies_) {
    $cookies = _$cookies_;
  }]);
});
```

Comment: this is what I needed to know. Thank you